# C# Display questions and wait for a response

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a WPF program that reads a question document (example below) and presents the question and answers in an appropriate way. But my question is how do i get my program to display one question and then wait for the answer before then displaying the next. The answers are displayed using the method `Display*Questiontype*(?).` eg `DisplayMultipleChoice(Question,CAnswer,Ianswer1,Ianswer2,Ianswer3)`.

Question Document;

& Multiple choice question 
~ Correct Answer 
- Incorrect Answer 
- Incorrect Answer 
- Incorrect Answer

? Textbox answer question 
~Correct Answer

$ Webpage Question 
@ Webpage

#### Here is a tried code

```
for (int i = 0; i < QuestionDocument.Length; i++)
            {

                if (QuestionDocument[i] == string.Empty)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                switch (QuestionDocument[i][0])
                {
                    case '&':
                        // get answers from document 
                        // DisplayMultiplechoice(Question,CAnswer,IAnswer1,IAnswer2,IAnswer3);
                        break;
                    case '?':
                        // get answers from document 
                        // DisplayMultiplechoice(Question,CAnswer,IAnswer1,IAnswer2,IAnswer3);
                        break;

                    case '#':
                        // get answers from document 
                        // DisplayMultiplechoice(Question,CAnswer,IAnswer1,IAnswer2,IAnswer3);
                        break;

                }
            }
```

Comment: If your issue is what I think it is, you need to use `Console.ReadLine`

Comment: @matiasfidemraizer generally there is nothing wrong with asking for help about homework.

Comment: It isn't homework, It's for a coursework project but help is needed

Comment: @tigerwhoops97 you should Show us what you habe tried so far. Some Code, and describe what your specific problem is

Comment: @derpirscher I agree, especially as it seems that OP has put effort into it and is not asking us to build the whole project, just for one *tiny* code snippet

Comment: @alfiegoodacre See my second comment

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework (or coursework) questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Added WPF tag as per comment on deleted answer

Comment: On deleted answer?

Comment: @derpirscher I believe that homework is meant to be done by yourself, and you should avoid asking for a solution. It might be fine if you ask a question about some specific issue and I would ask a question that wouldn't show that's actually homework at all....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for loop I used some methods that call each other